# Is accessing static data safe in job system?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to write on static list with job -  The newly intorduced Job System (multithreading system) in Unity.

The following code works but gives unexpected exception error only on start. Although removing burst compiler from job remove that error, But still Is it safe to use static data from job(without using burst if possible)?

```
 [BurstCompile]
 struct ColChecker : IJobParallelFor
 {
    public NativeArray<Vector3> pos;

    public static NativeArray<int> Iz;
    public int key;
    public int no;
    public void Execute(int index)
       { 
       /// Code to get no
       Iz[key] = no;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Try putting a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) on it!

Comment: @Maakep If possible can you provide me sample code ? I never used lock before and cannot able to understand where should I used it in my problem. Also it requires referance type where in job system everything is value type.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe because you can't guarantee nothing else will ever write into that field at the same time.

Instead, make Iz a non-static field, mark it with [ReadOnly] attribute and assign it before scheduling the job.